# ios-charts Draw grid lines only below data

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I need to draw grid lines (on line chart) only below the data. I couldn't find an API for it, yet.

Here I drew something showing what I get and what I need:

Top drawing is what I get.
Below is what I need.
Sorry for awful drawing talent :)

Any suggestions? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you read out -- https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Yes, I did, read again but somehow I miss the related part, again?

Comment: you can add custom view for represent data, and for graph use chart and customise it according your requirment.

Comment: I think you should define and use custom `XAxisRenderer`, pay your attention to two functions `renderGridLines(context: CGContext)` and `drawGridLine(context: CGContext, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)`.

Comment: Thank Alex. Will try.

Answer (score 5):

Another way. Use `fillFormatter` to fill the area where you don't want to see grid lines.

I check this code snippet with ChartsDemo-iOS-Swift example. In class `LineChart1ViewController` I changed part of `setDataCount()` function. I specifically used `white` color, so you can see the filled area.

```
//...
    set1.fillAlpha = 1
    set1.drawFilledEnabled = true
    set1.fillColor = .white
    set1.fillFormatter = DefaultFillFormatter { _,_  -> CGFloat in
        return CGFloat(self.chartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum)
    }
//...
```

Result

[image: filled area]

Comment: that's a good answer. You can choose the same color as the background under the graph and then everything will look good. But what if there is a gradient or a picture under the graph?